# Passwordless ssh not working even though normal steps taken

Tags: macos, ssh

Let's look at the "normal" steps to get passwordless ssh to work:

1. Create an ssh key `id_rsa`, add it to `~/.ssh` dir and do `chmod 0600` on it.
2. Add the `id_rsa.pub` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. ensure that file also is `0600`
3. Well, that should be sufficient for the following to work:

   ssh localhost

   ssh (hostname).local (since on mac)

However i'm getting the dreaded

```
Password:
```

So re-ran it with `-vv`:

```
 ssh -vv myhost.local
```

Here is the more interesting output portions:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/steve/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:lwo/CxupCjhYOL8I9MuCD8tQTbb2uIDHDVuTBb/npJk
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/steve/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/steve/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Notice in particular it *did* pick up

```
 Offering RSA public key: /Users/steve/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That's what I wanted But .. then why did it not get accepted?  What else should I look for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id_rsa` is corrupted.  I had used it in the past: so uncertain how that happened.

This was verified by generating a new key via `ssh-keygen -t rsa -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new` and then running

```
     ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new
```

and that worked.